# Intel XDK App Framework textarea gets focus only on every second tap

Tags: html, intel-xdk, jqmobi

I have a typical textarea in my panels:

```
<textarea name="textarea12"
          data-object-id="12"
          id="textarea12"
          cols="30"
          rows="10">
</textarea>
```

It only gets focus on the second tap/click/touch. The annoying thing is that when I inspect it in the Intel XDK debugger, it does get the class 'pressed' on every tap but it only gets focused on every second one.

Why does this happen?

Comment: My suspicion is that it has something to do with the 300ms delay that is typically inserted by the device OS to detect touch motion. Rather than detecting on touch start, try detecting touch end to see how it behaves. You might want to use a library like fastclick to resolve this.

Comment: Well it apparently works okey after building apk but seems to not work in debug mode for whatever reason.

Comment: Just for clarification -- when you say "debugger" do you mean the "Emulator tab" or the "Debug tab"? The two are quite different runtime environments.